# What are some differences between electric force and gravitational force?

Tags: forces, gravity, electricity

What are some differences between electric force and gravitational force? I mean, electric force is stronger, and electric force can be neutralized, but what else is there?

Answer (score 0):

The electrostatic force can be either attractive or repulsive, since charges come in either positive or negative form. But the gravitational force is always attractive because mass and energy (which are the things it responds to) only exist in positive form.

The electrostatic force only acts on objects that carry electrical charge, but the gravitational force acts on all objects even if they are electrically neutral.